# How to enable hover effect for Woocommerce Shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have two subdomain instances of the same WordPress site (dev & staging) which I'm synchronizing, yet, when rendered to the browser, there's a difference between the two which I cannot seem to find the source of.
The woocommerce **shop** page shows an image link for all the products.
One of the sites has a hover effect on that page, and the other doesn't.

(a detailed description would be difficult and verbose, so I'll include the url's in a comment below.
If there's a more appropriate way to clarify, please advise. I'm happy to oblige.)

Both instances are running identical WP versions as well as identical WooCommerce and Avada (theme) versions. They are both also on the same server.

Is there a WP or WC setting that I'm just overlooking somewhere?
We would like to enable it for the staging site like it is on the dev site.

---BTW, I'm pretty confident that the stylistic differences will be resolved once we figure out how to enable that hover effect for the staging site.

Comment: dev.cellperspectives.com/shop -vs- staging.cellperspectices.com/shop

Comment: And, fyi, there there's another example of a woocommerce element hover effect working on one site but not the other, YET there also several examples where they are identical between the two sites. ...I'm at a loss

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to add the first gallery image as a hover image on Woocommerce 3+.

This goes in your functions.php

```
 //add hover effect by grabing first gallery image
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'addHoverImageToProducts', 15 );

function addHoverImageToProducts() {
    global $product;
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    $count = 0;
    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) { 
        $count++;
        //make sure you're on the Shop Page and that you only get the first image
        if(is_shop() && $count <= 1){
    ?>
            <div class="product-secondary-image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' )[0]; ?> '); "></div>
    <?php 
        }
    }
}
```

This is your CSS

```
.product-secondary-image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 480px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.product:hover .product-secondary-image{
    opacity: 1;
}
```